# EXCEL - Updating NOT SHARED Master Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Let's imagine that we have 1 Master Excel File, which is not a shared workbook. I intended to use this workbook for the users to update a certain database. It means that multiple users may come in and update at the same time, however, keep in mind that this workbook is not shared. If the first person is in a file, the remaining users will be read-only. The reason behind this is because I have some tables in this workbook in order to make the workbook itself more dynamic, which, in turn, prevents the workbook from being shared.

So at this point, we will have 2 groups of user: a dominant user and read-only users.

My question is: whether it is possible for us to create such macro, which will save the version of the read-only users as a temp excel files. So that, when a dominant user close a file, it will automatically upload those temp file into the master excel workbook (I think Workbook_BeforeClose might do the job but don't know if it is possible). All these data, workbooks will be stored on a shared network among the mentioned users.

Thank you for your help.

Tony

Comment: So the second (read-only) user's changes then overwrite the first user's changes?

Comment: @TimWilliams it will update after what the first user inputted. Let say the user 1 update into row one, those available from user 2 will be from the second row after the user 1 save and before the workbook actually close.

Comment: So users are only ever adding information, never editing existing data?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, if there is a change, it will be a new row. This helps preventing the duplication.

Comment: I think you need to convert this Master file to only store data. Create another file to access this Master data file, retry open for couple times until not readonly when data update/sync is needed. Complicated but doable. Alternatively, convert the Master file to a Template, when users create a new one based on it, you only need to sync the difference - quickly open the Template and close saving changes. Since all changes are treated as new data row, it should be very quick.

Comment: @PatricK Thanks PatricK, I think I've found a way. I can instead turn this Master File into an entry form, so any user can come here, input the data, then it will update into a shared database.

Comment: Sounds good! Come back if stuck.